Garage Door opens fine but does not close the first try
I have a Liftmaster 2255. It is the house's original garage door opener. I have been having issues with the opener for the last 1 month (see a video I recorded below).
[Video displaying the issue] https://youtu.be/Gi2yPJWqqbA
Here are the things I have done so far:

Initially, the opener won't work due to issues with the gear sprocket, which I replaced. It was pain in the butt but I successfully fixed it. I used the following product ordered from amazon.

https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08SBW313J

Then, I replaced the garage door's bottom plastic seal. I used the following product. The original seal was a U-shape seal while this one has an O-ring in the seal. I ordered this because people say it is better than U-shape seals. One issue I observed was the following: It says it is a 16 ft seal, but I had to cut - probably - half a foot as it was bigger than my 16 ft garage door.

https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0CQ4S34CL
I thought I fixed everything, but the garage door started acting weird. When we open the garage door it works, but when I try closing it, it won't close in the first couple of trials. I had to click on the close button 4-5 times, which at the end it was closing. Not sure if replacement of the bottom seal with a U-O-Share seal is connected with my issue I am describing here. In fact, after this replacement, I started observing the garage door not closing in the first couple of trials.

Nevertheless, I thought that the rollers and hinges might be the reason. In fact, the rollers were rusted and some of the hinges were either bent or cracked at some different locations. Thus, I replaced all the rollers and hinges (except the top and bottom hinges). I used the following product for this purpose.

https://www.amazon.com/dp/B089YCBPGB

Then, I cleaned up all the rails with ECOLAB Citrus Degreaser, which I bought from Home Depot. I used BLASTER White Lithium Grease Spray on all the hinges, again bought from Home Depot.

The opener is an old type, probably from 2004, which uses a chain drive. I cleaned the beam rail with ECOLAB Degreaser, and then used the lithium grease on top of the rail. I have done this because the trolley moves along the beam rail such that the top part of the rail is being utilized by the trolley while opening and closing the garage door.


Issue still persists. The door opens normally, but when I try closing it, in the first or second try, it will just close until a random point, and then opens back up. After a couple of trials, it will close, however. Once it CAN close, I won't observe the opening/closing issue for some time. I am not sure what is going on and how I can decipher the culprit here. I used extra lithium grease on the gear sprocket after opening up the garage door opener, in case this might be the reason.
Some other Information: When I try closing the door by myself, it works fine. it is a heavy door. I think something is stopping the opener to close the door. I also played with the force settings, without any success. It can close even at low force settings, but when this issue happens it won't close in the first couple of trials.
Some extra Information: In order to install the bottom roller, I did two things. While installing one side of the bottom roller, I disassembled the vertical track, installed the roller, and assembled it again. It was not easy. Thus, for the other side, I bent the vertical track at one point using a pliers, installed the roller, and then fixed the bent with the pliers.
Any suggestions/ideas/solutions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Best regards,
Ilyas

Are you using a remote or the direct wire control to close? I'm thinking batteries? Occam's razor approach.

It happens in both cases. The garage door starts to close but then opens up. I do not think it is the battery; if that was the case it should not have sent the signal to the opener to close.

Is the door properly balanced, i.e. is the spring(s) wound correctly?  If you disconnect the electric opener from the door, you should be able to manually lift the door so the bottom is about 4 ft off the ground, and it should stay in place when you let go (assuming mechanism roll smoothly and nothing is binding).

Make sure your sensors are stabilized (not loose) and aligned. The sending sensor will be amber and the receiving sensor should have a green light. They should both be illuminated.to indicate proper alignment.

There does not seem to be any problem with the door balance; when I raise the door with my hands, it opens/closes without issues. I also double checked the sensors. Please check out the youtube video I uploaded.
youtu.be/Gi2yPJWqqbA
The weird thing is that, once the door fully closes, there are no more issues. I can open/close the door without any issues. Is it possible the sensors might have some problems? I am still thinking something is blocking something, but cannot figure it out. Maybe the rollers? Should I put back the old rollers? At this point, I am lost with any ideas...
